# How to compute difference of two images

Tags: computer-vision, ocr

I'm taking a course in image recognition. We've just been taught about corner detection, e.g Harris.
I'm wondering what would be the next step in computation after it?
Let's take for example an image from wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#/media/File:Corner.png
Lowercase n, denoting a power on t, resulted in tree points being detected.
If I were to use this data, what do I do with it to know it might be a 'n' letter? Is there a way to compute similarity of this line that n got transformed into against an alphabet of choice and pick a best match?
What if I'm not looking for something as simple as a black letter on white background?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Just for the records, I will state the [Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) method, here's a good paper for that matter : http://www.cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/coatesetal_icdar_2011.pdf

Also, OpenCV has it's own [implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_table_of_contents_ml/py_table_of_contents_ml.html) of it and it might work for your case, as long as it's somehow simple to do. More than that, you'll need a more sophisticated one or create your own (I don't recommend that !).